# Adding a parent for a child branch in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

In TFS, I have created a branch (say Child) from another branch (see below image for the hierarchy).
[image]

I need to change the hierarchy to include another one more parent in-between (see the below image).
[image]

How can I do that?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know I shouldnt comment on this without knowing the entire context, but anyways (from 40000 feet above) this doesnt look like a good branching strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right-click a branch in the source control explorer and pick "Reparent". Before you can reparent, you must ensure that the intermediate branch exists and that there is a branch relationship between the different branches. In the worst case you'll need to do a baseless merge from the commandline using `tf merge /recursive /baseless`

The process is explained here:

- http://roadtoalm.com/2012/09/19/reparent-of-a-source-controlled-branch-why-and-how/